# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError - pip install fail

Tags: python

I tried to install torch by pip but this is my error
 Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 42] Illegal byte sequence

it's happend a lot with others libs

What can i do to fix it?

Comment: What did you type in the command prompt?

Comment: Please post your setup (OS, python version etc.), the command you are trying to use and the full error message

Comment: Call `pip` with `-v` or `-vv` to get more details about the problem.